# Error when install Trove Openstack Juno

Tags: database, openstack, dbaas

I'm trying install Trove-Openstack Juno for Database service
I follow step by step in this doc http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt-debian/content/trove-install.html but i got an error message and i dont know how to resolve

`apt-get install python-trove python-troveclient python-glanceclient \
  trove-common trove-api trove-taskmanager`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-trove : Depends: python-sqlalchemy (< 0.9) but 0.9.7-1~cloud0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Please help me! Thank guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead [How To REALLY Install OpenStack Trove on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.hitchnyc.com/how-to-really-install-openstack-trove-on-ubuntu-14-04/)